# TypeScript Promise return type issue

Tags: typescript, promise

I am having a recursive `function` `traverseSchemas`, which traverse through nested `JSONschema` and parse them (`loadSchema` an `async` function) and return  some data structure.

Here I am trying to return the `data` => `[{object}, [object]]` .

```
const traverseSchemas =  async (
      filepath:string,
      isRoot: boolean
    ) => 
      {
      const refSchemaData = await loadSchema(
        filepath,
        isRoot
      )
      const refSchemas = generatePaths(refSchemaData, "$ref");
      const ref_ = _.filter(refSchemas, (o) => {
          if (o.values.includes(".json")) return o;
      });
      const schemaObj: Record<string, any> = {};
      schemaObj[_.get(refSchemaData, "$id")] = refSchemaData;
      
      const data = await Promise.all(_.map(ref_,  async (o) => {
            return await traverseSchemas(_.get(o, "values"), false)
        }).flat()).then((values) => {
          return [schemaObj].concat(values)
        })
  
      return data
    };
```

But I am getting below 2 errors

> 'traverseSchemas' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not
> have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly
> in one of its return expressions.
>
> 'data' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own
> initializer.

`console.log(data)` gives me desired output . I am guessing something very basic of `Promise` I am missing here.

Comment: This should be marked TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjy2IAl0_N4 this solution worked for me , not sure thats the best way to deal with that

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N9E13N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: "*I am guessing something very basic of Promise I am missing here.*" - no, this has nothing to do with promises specifically. It just says that TypeScript is unable to infer the return type of your function due to the recursion (pretty much a tsc limitation). So declare it as `async (filepath:string, isRoot: boolean): Promise<[object, object[]]> => {…}` (or whatever the expected return type is exactly)